# Can we three-color the plane so that each color misses a distance?

Tags: coloring

Is it possible to color each point in the plane either red, green, or blue, such that there are three numbers $r,g,b$ such that

- No two red points are a distance $r$ apart
- No two green points are a distance $g$ apart
- No two blue points are a distance $b$ apart?

For any particular $r,b,g$, if it is impossible to color the plane so as to miss these particular $r,b,$ and $g$, then I think it is possible to pick a finite number of points such that it is already impossible to color just those points in this way.  The proof of this is the same as [Gottschalk's proof of the De Bruijn-Erdös  theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(graph_theory)#Proofs'); namely, the space of all three-colorings of the plane under the product topology is compact by Tychonoff's theorem, so if any finite set of points can be colored to satisfy the condition, then the collection of sets $X_F$ of colorings of the plane that work for each finite set of points $F$ satisfies the finite intersection property and therefore there is a coloring in the intersection of all of them.

Related problems:

- The two-color version of this problem is done [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/2ColorsAllDistances.shtml)
- We can't have $r=b=g$, as shown [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/proofs/2ColorsAllDistances.shtml)
- The three-dimensional version of this problem is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348711/euclidean-geometry-problem-question-4-from-putnam-and-beyond)

Comment: This appears to be related to the Hadwiger-Nelson problem:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem  -- I  know too little about graph theory to provide you with an answer but given the known constraints on possible solutions for the minimum amount of colors required there, I would strongly assume the answer to your question is "No". At least this is very far from trivial...

Answer (score 2):

As a partial result, there is no measurable coloring with this property.

The [Moser spindle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moser_spindle) is a unit-distance graph with $7$ vertices and independence number $2$. If the set $R$ of red points doesn't have two points that are $r$ apart, then in any Moser spindle with edge length $r$, at most $2$ vertices out of $7$ are present.

We take a large square $S = [-n/2,n/2]^2$ with $n$ much larger than $\max\{r,g,b\}$. By an averaging argument, if $R$ is measurable, then $\mu(R \cap S) \le (\frac27 + o(1))n^2$. (A uniformly random copy of a Moser spindle with edge length $r$ contained in $S$ sees at most $2$ points of $R \cap S$.)

Similarly, if the set $G$ of green points and the set $B$ of blue points miss distances $g$ and $b$ respectively, and are measurable, then $\mu(G \cap S) \le (\frac27 + o(1))n^2$ and $\mu(B\cap S) \le (\frac27 + o(1))n^2$. So $\mu(S \setminus (R \cup G \cup B)) \ge (\frac17 + o(1))n^2$, and for sufficiently large $n$ this means some points of $S$ are left uncolored.

Comment: Consider taking the three Moser spindles, and use all their edges as vectors to generate a subgroup $\mathbb{Z}^d$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Repeat your argument in $\{0,...,n\}^d\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^d$ and you should be able to show no such coloring at all exists.

Comment: @EdwardH That sounds like it will work; I encourage you to write it up as an answer!